# Trying to write a basic loop, but my syntax is wrong

Tags: r, loops, statistics, dimensions

I'm very new to programming, and was wondering if someone could help me with some syntax. Basically, I'm trying to run a program that will create a vector of length 11, called lambda, that will have the first 11 correlations of a lagged data set. The vector with all of my data is already defined; it's called y and is of length 500. I have the following line of code with my function:

```
for(s in 0:10) {
    lambda(s) = cor(y[1:(500-s)], y[(1+s):500])
}
```

R keeps telling me that I have incompatible dimensions.

Comment: SO will format your code lines if you indent them 4 spaces.  Make all code self contained, i.e. inputs should be provided.

Comment: There's a difference between `(` and `[`. Don't assign `lambda(s) =`, try `lambda[s]`. Also you are starting the counter at zero, so `lambda[s+1]` to be precise.

Comment: Here is a good discussion of looping in R: http://blog.datacamp.com/tutorial-on-loops-in-r/

As you become a better R programmer, it's worth keeping in mind that looping in R---especially nested loops--- can be pretty slow. Where you don't have dependency between iterations of loops, you can generally get better performance from the *apply family of functions. If you have dependency between iterations (and you want to write code that will be used repeatedly) then it's worth learning to implement these loops in Rcpp or Stan (which is much closer to R syntax than Rcpp).

Comment: Try to give a reproducible example. What's in the variable y?

Answer (score 1):

Well, at fist glance I notice two syntax mistakes, first you should replace the round brackets '()' in vector lambda with square brackets '[]'. The other thing is that indexing of vectors in R starts from 1 not 0, so you should change that in the for loop. Try this modified for loop and see if it works or not. Good luck!

```
for(s in 1:11) {
lambda[s] = cor(y[1:(500-s)], y[(1+s):500])
}
```